# Writing to a C# array from C with PInvoke

Tags: c#, pinvoke, c#-2.0

I have a function like this :

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void Step(int * oSamplesCount, float * oSamples){
    // (approximative syntax for clarity)
    *oSamplesCount = new_samples_count (some number between 0 and 16000)
    oSamples[ 0 .. new_samples_count ] = some floats (sound data)
}
```

I'd like to call it from C# :

```
float [] mSamples = new float[16000];

[DllImport("Lib.dll")]
static extern void Step(ref Int32 oSamplesCount, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray,SizeConst=16000)] ref float [] oSamples);

void update(){
    Int32 lSamplesCount = 0;
    Step(ref lSamplesCount, ref mSamples);
}
```

The C function is called correctly, the for() loop that fills the samples array is ok, but it crashes somewhere between the return and the next C# line, so I guess it has something to do with unmarshalling, although I don't want any marshalling/unmarshalling (the array is blittable and must be written to from C)

I can't use /unsafe. I tried SizeConst and various other permutations.

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

Your pinvoke is wrong. The array parameter should not be passed by `ref` since a `float[]` is already a reference. Do it like this:

```
[DllImport("Lib.dll")]
static extern void Step(ref Int32 oSamplesCount, float[] oSamples);
```

Note that this will marshal from managed to native, and back again, all 16000 values, on each call to `Step`. If that's too expensive then I think you will need to perform manual marshalling.

Comment: You're right, float[] is already a reference. That was my mistake. But if I use UnmanagedType.LPArray, will it still marshall/unmarshall the 16000 floats ?

Comment: Yes it will. The default marshalling for `float[]` is `UnmanagedType.LPArray` so you don't need to specify that. Your interface is very odd. The native code appends each time. I'd probably do this with AllocHGlobal and then copy all the floats into a `float[]` right at the end, once I'd finished calling `Step`.