# How to marshall fixed byte array for C function

Tags: c#, c, marshalling

Hi I have been working to create a wrapper for dll of a third party C library to be used in C#.

Suppose I have C function from the library:

```
void functionA(byte data[16], byte buffer[8]);
```

Is it correct for the following code to be used to wrap the code above ?:

```
[DllImport("C.dll",CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void functionA(byte[] data, byte[] buffer)
```

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892734/writing-to-a-c-sharp-array-from-c-with-pinvoke.

Answer (score -1):

No, that declaration would only be valid for `byte *data`, which is a pointer to an array.

What you have is a fixed size array, for which you need the following

```cs
[DllImport("C.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void functionA(
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16]
  byte[] data,
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8]
  byte[] buffer)
```